# AngularJS How access at content of {{ x.id }} from js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

i'm a newbie with angularJS and actually i am working on Activiti.

I need to access an url with a specific ID (example taskId=12333) that change when a form is submitted.

**How i can dynamically change the url so the taskId correspond to the new id?** .

Here i get all task id (json format):

```
function githubController3($scope, $http, Base64) {

$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('kermit' + ':' + 'kermit');

$http.get("http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/runtime/tasks")
    .then(function (response, data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.names = response.data.data;
    });};
```

And the answer:
[json Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZaBu.png)

I need to take ID from this answer and so form new URL.

```
function githubControllerForm1($scope, $http, Base64) {

$http.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Basic ' + Base64.encode('kermit' + ':' + 'kermit');

$http.get("http://localhost:8080/activiti-rest/service/form/form-data?taskId=" + "**//here i need new ID dynamically**") 
    .then(function (response, data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.names = response.data.formProperties;
    });};
```

Actually i get id with this in html:

```
<div ng-controller="githubController3">
                <div ng-repeat="y in names">
                    {{ y.id }}
```

It's possible to assign the value of {{y.id}} to a $http.get request?

Thanks everyone that could help. Sorry if i was a bit unclear :)

Comment: you are already getting the value from the response. why dont you get it there?

Comment: What will trigger the `$http.get()` when using `y.id`? You have that logic in a ng-repeat. Will a user be clicking a button, link, etc?

Comment: Thanks for answers :)

@John F. Yes user input some text in a form, then click submit and post request is send. So after this a new form with new ID should be displayed... The problem is that i don't know how change url (dynamically?) with this new ID...

Comment: @Sajeetharan how? :(